# Selecting top 3 distinct records from a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this which contains the columns: **country, woeid, sometopic, LastDateTime**

```
 Venezuela  23424982    Metoo
 Venezuela  23424982    Chaderton
 India      25424282    BossAgain
 World      1           EL AVIADOR
 Venezuela  23424982    ChicagoBurning and so on...
```

I want distinct country to be selected and only top 3 rows.

I want the result to be like this ordered by LastDateTime.

```
 Venezuela  23424982    Chaderton
 India      25424282    BossAgain
 World      1           EL AVIADOR
```

I tried like this:

```
 select distinct(country), woeid, sometopic, * from PopularTrends  order by LastModifiedTime desc
```

but this didnot work.

any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT COUNTRY,WOEID,SOMETOPIC,LASTDATETIME
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   PARTITION BY COUNTRY
                   ORDER BY LASTDATETIME) AS RN
        FROM   #Yourtable)A
WHERE  RN = 1
```